# How to generate <p id="r1_c1"> with ruby interpolation?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, sass, erb

I have a need to generate an html id using some .erb code.  Specifically, I want to use the row and column index of a cell in a rectangular array (made out of a table of cells).  I have a method cell.web_id, which constructs a string thus:

```
"r#{row_index}_c#{column_index}",
```

so that cell(2,3) would yield

```
"r2_c3".
```

So far, so good.

Now for the odd part. I haven't figured out how to wrap the web_id result in double quotes required to properly define the attribute.  No matter what I try, I always get:

```
<span class="cell" id=&quot;r1_c1&quot; >
```

This form doesn't work.

So, how can I get this form:

```
<span class="cell" id="r2_c3" >
```

I know this is easy if you know the proper incantation, but I don't have it.

Answer (score 1):

Try  this:

```
<span class="cell" id="<%="r#{row_index}_c#{column_index}"%>" >
```

**OR**

```
<span class="cell" id="r<%=row_index%>_c<%=column_index%>" >
```

**OR**

```
<span class="cell" id="<%=foo_span_id(row_index, column_index)%>" >
```

Where `foo_span_id` is a custom helper method

Comment: The first alternative worked great.  My problem was that I did not consider using an .erb escape sequence within a string, I did not think it would parse properly.  I live and learn. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`"\"r#{row_index}_c#{column_index}\"".html_safe`

[(apidock docs)](http://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe) (mostly useless, but included for completeness :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead double quotes, why don't you try single quotes? (that is normally what I do in situations like this).

So your code will be

```
"'r#{row_index}_c#{column_index}'"
```

and your HTML will also need to be slightly changed to single quotes

```
<span class='cell' id='r2_c3'; >
```